# Is it possible to customise the menu options from the datagrid materialUI columns?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I'm trying to use Datagrid from MaterialUI to display a list of people. I'm wondering if I can change the options selected by materialUI, meaning changing which ones will show up, and also change the text that appears of them (you can see that on the picture below with the red box).

For example, I want to remove the options Sort by ASC and DESC from the box, since I have those options already in the arrow at the left of the three dots. Also I wanna change the texts from Unsort and Filter. It's possible to do that? Thanks

[image]